# Infintely many $n$ such that $an+1$, $bn+1$, $cn+1$ are primes?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Let $a, b, c$ be natural numbers. Is it known that there exist infinitely many $n$ such that $an+1$, $bn+1$, $cn+1$ are primes? or is this problem out of reach of the current knowledge regarding prime numbers? Thank you.

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions#:~:text=Linnik's%20theorem%20(1944)%20concerns%20the,have%20reduced%20L%20to%205.), as this implies that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $an+1$ is prime for any $a\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: The closest result is [Green–Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem#Extensions_and_generalizations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is out of reach, even with just two terms instead of three. This is a special case of ["Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture), which is extremely similar to the the "prime $k$-tuples conjecture".

Comment: yeah but if not all same parity in $a,b,c$ we have that any $n$ is even, or they are all even in $a,b,c$ . probably more you can say.